# apt-get 'held broken packages' attempting to install kubuntu-desktop

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde

```
$sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kubuntu-desktop : Depends: kde-workspace-bin but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: language-selector-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: plasma-netbook but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: akregator but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apport-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: jockey-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kaddressbook but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kde-config-touchpad but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdepim-kresources but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdepim-runtime but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kdepim-strigi-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kmail but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: knotes but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kontact but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: kopete but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: korganizer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon-installer but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: muon-notifier but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-widget-facebook but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-widgets-addons but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: printer-applet but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: system-config-printer-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: usb-creator-kde but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: userconfig but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
$cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted multiverse universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
```

---

```
$cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/steam/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/steam/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb http://apt.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release restricted

deb http://apt.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release restricted

deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gvfs-libmtp/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu precise main
# Wuala repository
deb http://repo.wuala.com stable main
# Wuala repository
deb http://repo.wuala.com stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
shane@moses:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins/ubuntu precise main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/ stable main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mqchael/pipelight/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/phablet-team/tools/ubuntu precise main
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/steam/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/steam/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
deb http://apt.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release restricted

deb http://apt.spideroak.com/ubuntu-spideroak-hardy/ release restricted

deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gvfs-libmtp/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu precise main
# Wuala repository
deb http://repo.wuala.com stable main
# Wuala repository
deb http://repo.wuala.com stable main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu precise main
```

thanks in advance

=============EDIT

the /etc/apt/sources.list file looks different now 'cause I did some things

okay, so before I posted this question I attempted to follow very thoroughly the other post that one of you suggested was a pre-existing answer to this issue.

-second, I checked the ubuntu ppa manager (with the gui and checkboxes and such) and the checkbox for the universe ppa is selected.  I disabled, and re-enabled it from here because I am afraid of messing with the file directly.  Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but I noticed I have backports enabled in the settings area..

-I figure this is the issue, which would mean that I have to roll back my updates or use the backports ppa of kubuntu..? is it possible that I would have enabled backports manually in order to install some third party software's dependencies?

================EDIT

```
$apt-cache policy kde-workspace-bin kubuntu-desktop

kde-workspace-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
     4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4:4.8.2a-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
kubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.254
  Version table:
     1.254 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

=======Edit

please don't mark this question as duplicate.. if you are referring to this post:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I have followed through all the suggestions and now, I am following through with the suggestion to post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

Comment: You have to enable the universe repository, and then try apt-get update, then install. Wow, that is a ton of ppa ;)

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy kde-workspace-bin kubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Updated @Braiam